# How to conditionally render an HTML property?

Tags: html, typescript, svelte

On my project, I'm using PicoCSS as a default style.

I have a form on which I want to highlight the fields that have errors whenever there's some problem while sending it.

To do that, I want to conditionally render the `aria-invalid` tag, because if I set it to "false", it is highlighted in green, and the behavior I want is to show only the error validation.

The piece of code is similar to the following:

```
<script>
   export let form: ActionData;
   // here I have the property "form.errors.firstName", which will be populated if I have an error
</script>
<form>
    <input name="first-name" />
    <!-->how to populate HTML property aria-invalid only if form.errors.firstName is thruty? I don't want to populate it as "aria-invalid='false'"</!-->
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
   export let form: ActionData;
   // here I have the property "form.errors.firstName", which will be populated if I have an error
</script>
<form>
    <input name="first-name" 
           class="form-input" 
           aria-invalid="${form.errors.firstName ? 'true' : undefined}" />
</form>
```

Here, we are using the ternary operator to conditionally render the aria-invalid attribute. If **form.errors.firstName** is true, it sets the aria-invalid attribute to "true", otherwise, it sets it to undefined.

Comment: This will result to `aria-invalid="$true"` because the template string was missing the backticks if you meant to make one. But there's no need for it anyway since the value will always be a string, so this could be `aria-invalid={form.errors.firstName ? true : undefined}` instead